# How can I install a system app without restarting the device?

Tags: installation, system-apps

I have a requirement to install two APKs in the `/system/priv-app` directory. But I can't restart the device (this is due to business requirements).

So, is there any way I can install the two APKs in the `/system/priv-app` directory without restarting the device?

Comment: This is a bit strange. To install an app as a system app a user needs to have root access. And rooted devices and businesses don't go hand in hand. Second, installation of an app as a system app is technically a *hack*, not something system provides as a feature to use.

Comment: Yes, it's really a bit strange. But now there is indeed such a situation.
Although we can install an apk as a system app by modifying the android image, this is more troublesome (requiring cooperation departments to schedule).
So I want to ask if there is a way to install the system application without restarting.

Comment: Try restarting the Android framework i.e. `system_server` and `zygote` (with `stop` and `start` commands). I think it should rescan the system partition. Never tried though. If it doesn't work, other native services may also be restarted. I can think of `installd` at the moment.

Comment: Previously posted on SO for possible additional context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73356758/2821954; there's [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356758/how-can-i-install-a-system-app-without-reboot#comment129548131_73356758) by [Martin Zeitler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler): "*It is not true that one would have to restart; while leaving the block device mounted.*"